# Knockout mapping from multiple sources into a single list without removing unlisted items

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have two lists of data and want to merge them into a single list with knockout mapping.

This seems to work ok if I define a key to compare on, except that it removes items not listed in the most recent update.

**Is there a way of using KO Mapping to an array without having it remove items that dont occur in the latest list?**

EG below, should produce:

- 1 A B
- 2 AA BB
- 3 AAA
- 4 BBB

not

- 1 A B
- 2 AA BB
- 4 BBB

```
    <ul data-bind='foreach: mergedList'>
        <li>
            <span data-bind='text: id'></span>
            <span data-bind='text: a'></span>
            <span data-bind='text: b'></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

```
    var listA = [
        { id: 1, a: 'A'},
        { id: 2, a: 'AA'},
        { id: 3, a: 'AAA'}
    ];
    var listB = [
        { id: 1, b: 'B'},
        { id: 2, b: 'BB'},
        { id: 4, b: 'BBB'}
    ];

    var mapping = {
        key: function(data) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
        },
        create: function (options){
            var model = new subViewModel();
            ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, model);
            return model;
        }
    }

    var subViewModel = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.a = ko.observable();
        self.b = ko.observable();
    }

    var viewModel = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.mergedList = ko.observableArray();
    }

    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(listA, mapping, vm.mergedList);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(listB, mapping, vm.mergedList);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BQRur/9/

Comment: Why not make two lists then combine. Is there an advantage in using mapping like this.

Comment: @Kieran in my actual code I'm not going to be merging them both in at the same time. I have 2 separate data sources which are updated independently via ajax and if I can avoid it it would be great to let something like KO Mapping do that merge together for me. It does actually do this already except I cant work out how to not trim the array when something doesnt exist in the new dataset.

Comment: This is not supported by the mapping plugin, the missing elements will be always removed it is not configurable. This is not the goal of the mapping plugin to merge different sources, but to map and update from one source. So you will need to implement the merging yourself...

Comment: @nemesv you may be right in that there is no way to avoid removing items which aren't listed, but it does actually list mapping from multiple sources in the documentation as a valid scenario. (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#mapping_from_multiple_sources) but doesn't say too much about the detail. I was hoping for some options around how this works but perhaps these aren't yet avaliable

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old so this might not help Luke but it might help others who come here from google (like me).
I had a similar problem recently and got help in the knockout forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/22DzjfgUzMs

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from using a [Computed Observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to produce this behavior?

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(listA,mapping,vm.listA);
ko.mapping.fromJS(listB,mapping,vm.listB);

vm.mergedList= ko.computed(function(){
return listA().concat(listB());
});
```

Comment: This wont actually produce a merged list if I have `[{id:1, a: '1'},{id:2, a: '2'}]` and merge with `[{id:1, b: '1'},{id:3, b: '3'}]` then I am expecting `[{id:1, a: '1', b: '1'},{id:2, a: '2'},{id:3, b: '3'}]` your approach will produce `[{id:1, a: '1'},{id:2, a: '2'},{id:1, b: '1'},{id:3, b: '3'}]`

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suit your needs?

```
    var listA = ko.observableArray([
        { id: 1, a: 'A'},
        { id: 2, a: 'AA'},
        { id: 3, a: 'AAA'}
    ]);

    var listB = ko.observableArray([
        { id: 1, b: 'B'},
        { id: 2, b: 'BB'},
        { id: 4, b: 'BBB'}
    ]);

    function viewModel () {
        var self = this;

        self.mergedList = ko.computed(function () {
            var result = [];

            // Build an associative array, ensure the object shape is defined as a default, or the bindings will fail on the missing entries (id 3 missing b, id 4 missing a).
            $.each(listA().concat(listB()), function (i, o) {
                result[o.id] = $.extend({}, result[o.id] || { id: null, a: null, b: null }, o);
            });

            // Extract only the entries from the associative array.
            result = $.map(result, function (o) {
                return o;
            });

            return result;
        });
    }

    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    // Async requests to update listA / listB here.
```

I had to add a reliance on jquery to make the above work, however the principle is the same if you remove the jquery reliance.  Mapping wasn't going to solve that particular issue as the key would be used to remove the items that didn't appear in listB.